# Modify table name at runtime

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I want to take a backup of a table with the timestamp value linked in the backup table.So that it can be easily figured out to which date this backup belongs to.I am trying something like this which is obviously not working.

Please suggest how to modify table name at runtime.

Scenario:

```
Insert into original_table+'_'+Convert(varchar(10),GETDATE(),112)
select * from original_table
```

The output should be:

A table should be created original_table_20141015 with the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can build a SQL string with the new table name, then execute it using `sp_executesql`.

Example:

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(MAX)
SET @sql = 'SELECT * INTO original_table_' +
    CONVERT(varchar(8), GETDATE(), 112) +
    ' FROM original_table'
EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```